# Проблемы с разделением строчек и кортежами Python 3.7.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, сортировка, tuple

Доброго всем времени суток. Имеется одна проблема. Нужно считывать с одной строки: Имя_Фамилию_число_число_число (вместо '_' используется пробел ' ') и добавлять его потом в список через кортеж и отсортировать, вылезает ошибка:

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 5)

при любой попытке ввода.

До подобной идеи доходило долго (только недавно начал учить Pитон...После Паскаля)

```
n=int(input())
marks = []
for i in range(n):
    fname, lname, mark1, mark2, mark3 = input().split(" ")
    name = fname + " " + lname
    mark_sum = int(mark1) + int(mark2) + int(mark3)
    marks.append((mark_sum, name))
marks.sort(reverse=True) # сортировка проходит по первому значению в tuple
for i in range(3):
    print(marks[i][1])
```

Comment: Покажите, что именно вы вводите-то и в какой строчке вылезает ошибка

Comment: "И добавлять его потом в список через кортеж" - это как?

Comment: Что делает код `for i in range(3):
    print(marks[i][1])`? Почему _3_?

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0, последний цикл очевидно для тестирования.

Comment: но почему там 3, для меня загадка)

Answer (score 2):

Такая ошибка возможна, если вы вводите неверно количество данных.
Также пишите условие, а то непонятно, что вы хотите.
Вот, пробуйте.

```
n=int(input())
marks = []

for i in range(n):
    fname, lname, mark1, mark2, mark3 = input().split(" ")
    name = fname + " " + lname
    mark_sum = int(mark1) + int(mark2) + int(mark3)
    marks.append((mark_sum, name))

marks.sort(reverse=True) # сортировка проходит по первому значению в tuple

for i in range(len(marks)):
    print(marks[i][1])
```

Входные данные

```
 2
 abc d 23 1 35
 dd e 1 2 3
```

Выход:

```
abc d
dd e
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка очевидно возникает в команде

```
fname, lname, mark1, mark2, mark3 = input().split(" ")
```

всякий раз, когда в вводной строке более чем 5 частей, как например в строке

> ```
> Ольга Зайцева 12 000 765 3
> ```

или

> ```
> Сергей Иванович Сахаров 4 5 6
> ```